# What is the best way to reference other rows in an SQL table?

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a table which has nodes in them. I want to have different groups of these nodes so that if I want to delete a node, I will also have the ability to delete the whole group if I wish.

What would be the best way about going about this?

I thought maybe make a table with group ids in and add a row in each node saying what group id it belongs to, but this doesn't seem the best method of doing it to me.

Any ideas would be great,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what you already proposed:

```
1) Create a GROUP table, with a GROUP_ID primary key
2) Create a NODE table, with a foreign key to NODE_GROUP
3) Define the foreign key relationship as DELETE CASCADE
```

If you want to delete all the nodes within a GROUP, then you can either delete the NODEs with a given GROUP_ID or delete the GROUP itself which will delete all the child NODEs.

If you need to assign NODEs to different GROUPs then you would need a third table e.g. GROUP_NODE which would link GROUP_IDs to NODE_IDs, but I don't think you wanted that.

Answer (score 1):

If the cardinality of the relationship is *zero-to-many*,

- give the node table a foreign key to the group table
- make the foreign key column(s) nullable

If the cardinality of the relationship is *one-to-many* (meaning a node must belong to a group),

- give the node table a foreign key to the group table
- make the foreign key columns non-nullable
- If the nature of the relationship between node and group is

  - **Identifying.** This means that the dependent entity (node) is predicated upon the existence of the containing entity (group). It may not be moved from one containing entity to another. If so, make the foreign key column(s) a part of the primary key of the the node table.
  - **Non-Identifying.** This means that the existence of the dependent entity (node) is not dependent on the existence of a particular containing entity (group). It may be moved from one containing entity to another. If so the foreign key column(s) should be independent of the primary key of the node table.

If the cardinality of the relationship between node and group is *many-to-many*, then you must introduce an associative entity into the mix, as *many-to-many* relationship are not directly supported by the relational model. That table will look like this:

```
create table dbo.GroupNode
(
  group_id int not null ,
  node_id  int not null ,

  constraint GroupNode      primary key ( group_id , node_id ) ,
  constraint GroupNode_FK01 foreign key references dbo.Node( node_id ) ,
  constraint GroupNode_FK02 foreign key references dbo.Group( group_id ) ,
)
```

Finally, if you wish dependent entity instances to vanish when a node or group is deleted, add `on delete cascade` clauses to the appropriate foreign keys.

Easy!

Answer (score 0):

You could have 3 tables, one for your nodes, one for your groups and one for your group memberships. Something like:

```
Nodes
-----
id (pk)
name
```

,

```
Group
----------
id (pk)
name
description
```

,

```
NodeGroup
----------
groupId (pk)
nodeId  (pk)
```

This will allow you to assign nodes to multiple groups (one to many relationship) and will also make it easy for you to figure out which nodes belong to a given group.

Comment: What would the primary key be in this..?

Comment: on the Node table, it would be the id, on the NodeGroup table it would be a composite of NodeId and GroupId